# How to include script bundle in scripts section in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a layout with an `@RenderSection("scripts")` section and I have a bundle that would need to be included in this section for *some* views. I thought that just doing this in the view would work, but it's not rendering the scripts.

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myBundle")  
}
```

**In my view, how can I include a bundle to the scripts section?**

Layout

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/scripts")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

View

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/movie")  
}
```

Comment: This should definitely work and is supported. I would check for typos in the bundle name - e.g. makes sure its `~/bundles/movie` and not `~/scripts/movie` in your `BundleConfig`.

Comment: I'm incredibly late here, but apparently even in VS2015 this can happen. The code is right, but I had to restart VS to get it rendering correctly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why mix the rendersection with bundling? If you choose to down the route of bundling, you can simply put your scripts in .JS file ,put it in their own bundle if you like and call that bundle on your view. For ex:

```
     bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myscripts").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/myscript1.js",
                    "~/Scripts/myscript2.js"));
```

then view will have the following:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myscripts")
```

Also make sure your Web.config has compilation debug set to false like below:

```
  <compilation debug="false" />
```

it makes sure the scripts are bundled and minified.

**Update**

Based on comments and my recent experience, I can see why would we want to use the two together. Perfect case of learning in the community! :) So, if you decide to come back for refactoring, I would make sure there are no typos to begin with. If it still does not work, please let me know what the problem is and I will update the answer accordingly. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Because I need the bundle to load after the jquery bundle in the layout. By just rendering the bundle like above in my view it will render before the jquery bundle.

Comment: Usually I put the jQuery bundle right at the top unlike the default at the bottom of the page and everything works fine. checkout this MVC music store code https://github.com/tekpub/mvcmusic/tree/master/MvcMusicStore

Comment: You may not want to render everything on every page. Sectioning gives you control of that. Putting everything in head is a horrible solution (jQuery may be an exception).

Answer (score 38):

Try below mentioned solution inside the **View**.

**View**

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/movie")"></script>
}
```

Comment: Why should this be the accepted answer?
It ignores the `debug` flag.

Comment: @Dementic Why don't you put your own answer then ?

Comment: it wasn't working until i removed "?v=4" in bundle "~/Content/css/my.css?v=4". I Use to clear browser cache when the styles change.

Answer (score 2):

I can not replicate the issue you are having

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/movie")  
}
```

renders fine with no issue (and respects the debug flag)
i would agree with @Mrchref and revisit your paths

on the other hand, you could use something like this:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static HtmlString StaticContent(this System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper url, string contentPath)
    {
        return new HtmlString(System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(contentPath).ToString());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@section Scripts{
    @Url.StaticContent("~/assets/js/jquery")
}
```

i would advise not to use it as is,
You would need to find another solution for `System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(contentPath).ToString()` since it basically renders the same function you are using (and not working).

You should play around with `System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles` and see if you can query for both version, check the debug flag, and serve the correct content.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a new build would solve your problem. Please follow these steps if not:

- **Step 1:** add this into `BundleConfig.cs`

  `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/common").Include("~/Scripts/common.js"));`
- **Step 2:** add this line in your `view/layout`

  `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/common")`
- **Step 3:** build your project and run it.