# Asp.Net Mvc Bundles and Specific Views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I use DataTables in some specific tables and it needs at least 10 different js/css files to work in my situation. So i tried to put them in a bundle and called that bundle in that view. But no success.

My question is that: Are bundles only for entire site (loads in every page) or can i use some of them in specific views only?

BundleConfig

```
bundles.Add(new     ScriptBundle("~/Content/DataTablesJS").Include("~/Content/DataTables/*.jss"));
bundles.Add(new     StyleBundle("~/Content/DataTablesCSS").Include("~/Content/DataTables/*.css"));
```

View

```
@section Styles
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/DataTablesCSS")

}

    @section Scripts
    {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/DataTablesJS")
    <script src="~/Content/SayfaJSs/DataTables.jss" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    DataTables.init();
    });
    </script>
    }
```

HTML Output

```
 <script src="/Content/DataTablesCSS?v=z-Ctaq2TbplDFpORl0e9NGH8TjpB5hQ2cPam2OxmDEo1"></script>

 <script src="/Content/DataTablesJS?v=2gXGKlcqr0bFFqv6Bbr9jB_7LVvvHDrghzBwHCgFJds1"></script>
```

Comment: can you show code that now working?

Comment: `("~/Content/DataTables/*.jss"));`... ".jss", is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

In your layout you would have something like this:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

...Then in your view you would add your bundle reference like this:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/yourBundle")
}
```

Comment: take a look in your page source, see what is being output. Also, Is it in a full view or an Ajax partial view?

Comment: I added output also. It's normal view.

Comment: Plus i changed WebConfig Debug=False.

Comment: I guess i should not put them in @section?

Comment: You don't need to do `WebConfig Debug=False` in your web.config, you could instead add this `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; ` to your bundleConfig.cs

Comment: I put false because of that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660868/how-to-include-script-bundle-in-scripts-section-in-view

Comment: Jss is not misspelled. I did it to copy here else editor window show error. I don't know why. Anyway it's not a problem.

Comment: Ok i found the problem. It's in my second post.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It was using asterisk to get all scripts in folder. From asp.net website:

"Adding scripts by wildcard defaults to loading them in alphabetical order, which is typically not what you want. "

My scripts needs a special order. So i included them in order that i need:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/DataTablesCSS")
            .Include("~/Content/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/DataTables/buttons.dataTables.min.css",
            "~/Content/DataTables/select.dataTables.min.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/DataTablesJS")
            .Include("~/Content/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
            "~/Content/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js",
            "~/Content/DataTables/dataTables.buttons.min.js",
            "~/Content/DataTables/dataTables.select.min.js",
            "~/Content/DataTables/buttons.bootstrap.min.js",
            "~/Content/DataTables/jszip.min.js",
            "~/Content/DataTables/pdfmake.min.js",
            "~/Content/DataTables/vfs_fonts.js",
            "~/Content/DataTables/buttons.html5.min.js",
            "~/Content/DataTables/buttons.print.min.js"));
```