# asp.net MVC Core - load partial view using Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views

In my MVC Core application, I want to load a partial view after the form is submitted.

After the form in `_TransferForm` is submitted, another partial view will be loaded instead of refreshing the entire page. Below are my code.

Why `_ApplySuccess` occupies the entire page, instead of displaying as a part of the page in `Apply`?

I have added `<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js">` in the shared `_Layout`.

**The parent View** `Apply.cshtml`:

```
@Html.Partial("_ApplyForm")

@section Scripts {
  <script>
    // delegate submit event to document, since form might be replaced
    $(document).on('submit', '#applyForm', function () {
        var $theForm = $(this);
        // manually trigger validation
        if ($theForm.valid()) {
            $('#progress').show();
            $.post('', $theForm.serialize())
                .done(function (response) {
                    $theForm.replaceWith(response);
                })
        }
        return false;
    });
  </script>   
}
```

**The partial view** `_ApplyForm.cshtml`:

```
<form id="applyForm" asp-action="Apply" asp-controller="Jobs">
// content
</form>
```

**The partial view** `_ApplySuccess.cshtml`:

```
<div>Successfully applied.</div>
```

**The controller's action** `Apply` :

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Apply(Applicant applicant)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // code

            return PartialView("_ApplySuccess");
        }
        return PartialView("_ApplyForm");
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include script bundle in scripts section in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660868/how-to-include-script-bundle-in-scripts-section-in-view)

Comment: @ebramkhalil This doesn't help. I have edited my question by the way.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After I removed the condition `if ($theForm.valid())`, it works. The method `valid()` is not defined somehow while compiling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootbox alert to show that process completed and successfully applied message in alert because you don't show any other details in partial view.

```
 $(document).on('submit', '#applyForm', function () {
    var $theForm = $(this);
    // manually trigger validation
    if ($theForm.valid()) {
        $('#progress').show();
        $.post('', $theForm.serialize())
            .done(function (response) {
                $theForm.replaceWith(response);
            })
   bootbox.alert({
title: '<h4 style="color:white">Alert</h4>',
message: '<p  style="font-weight:700;">successfully applied</p>'
});

    }
    return false;
});
```

you can get reference by refer this http://bootboxjs.com/ link

Comment: Thanks for the alternative way to do it

Comment: welcome Matt.. if you find this helpful then you can make this as answer